# Redirection from filter in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, session-timeout

How do I track the first HTTP request when a session will get initialized and allow it from a filter?

After initializing this session "it" will always pass through the filter.

Comment: You must work on your question, it's a bit unclear. Your description implies that your filter will always pass requests through, do you mean _reject_ instead of _allow_?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a session attribute as a boolean flag:

```
    HttpSession sess = request.getSession();
    Object o = sess.getAttribute("FIRST_HIT");
    if (o == null) {
        //execute first hit stuff here
        sess.setAttribute("FIRST_HIT", "FIRST_HIT");
    }
```

Where 'request' ISA javax.servlet.ServletRequest

This is an 'execute only once per session' style logic since we are storing the boolean flag in the session object (or session scope)